# Why does IsUTF8String return false?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have some simple code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender:TObject);
var
  x: RawByteString;
begin
  x := UTF8Encode('testing utf8');
  if (IsUTF8String(x)) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('true');
end;
```

This returns False, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no special characters in that string that would require UTF-8 encoding — there are no multibyte UTF-8 sequences in the string. It looks like a plain ASCII string.

If there's anything you can do to the design of your program that would eliminate the need to *guess* about the encodings of your strings, I recommend you do it. Guesses can be wrong. Try not to be wrong about your customers' data.

Comment: Ahhh I get it, thank you.  I just added a special character and now I see it returning true.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: The documentation states: IsUTF8String does not guarantee that the string is UTF-8 encoded. IsUTF8String attempts to determine the encoding by checking the characters present in the string.

Comment: @David, I wonder whether the implementation of this function is much more than simply `Result := DetectUTF8Encoding(s) = etUTF8`.

Comment: @Rob It is precisely that, except that the VCL version spells the function return value `result` rather than `Result`!!! Not bad for a man without Delphi!

Comment: Well, it's case insensitive, so both would have compiled fine.

Comment: Yes, @Warren. David was simply remarking at how closely my blind guess matched the actual implementation. The only source I have is from Delphi 2005, which is of course no help with this question.